# How can I show/hide mobile navbar on click using useState? React + TypeScript + Tailwind project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

As the subject, I tried to show/hide the mobile navbar on click using "useState", but the menu does not show it when I click. How can I fix it?

[image: This is the mobile current mobile view.]
[image: This is the current web view.]

This is the actual code that is related to this problem.

```
  const [navbarOpen, setNavbarOpen] = useState(false)
  return (
   
      {/* mobile navbar */}
      <div className='cursor-pointer'>
        <div className='flex justify-between md:hidden px-8 py-4'>
          <div className='flex'>
            <button>
              <svg
                xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                className='w-8 h-8 text-white p-2 bg-indigo-500 rounded-full flex self-center'
                viewBox='0 0 24 24'
                onClick={onClickHome}
              >
                <path d='M12 2L2 7l10 5 10-5-10-5zM2 17l10 5 10-5M2 12l10 5 10-5'></path>
              </svg>
            </button>
            <span className='ml-3 text-md cursor-pointer' onClick={onClickHome}>
              Chat App
            </span>
          </div>
          <svg
            xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
          >
          </svg>
        </div>
       {/* collapsable navbar */}
        <div className={  navbarOpen ? ' flex' : ' hidden'}>
          <div
            onClick={onClickUserManagement}
            className='text-center block text-base hover:text-gray-900 mb-1'
          >
            User All
          </div>
          <div
            onClick={onClickSetting}
            className='text-center block text-base hover:text-gray-900 mb-1'
          >
            Setting
          </div>
          <div
            onClick={onClickSetting}
            className='text-center block text-base hover:text-gray-900 mb-1 pb-4'
          >
            Third Link
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  )
})
```

Comment: I don't see anything calling `setNavbarOpen(true)`, you need to call that.

Comment: Thank you so much! True, I forgot to add onClick={() => setNavbarOpen(!navbarOpen)} to the menu icon. Thanks.

Comment: Well, now the mobile menu is kept opening after I click it to show on mobile, and enlarge it to tablet/web view. <div className={navbarOpen ? ' flex' : ' hidden'}> I want to add "md-hidden" to the className to solve it. How can I do that?

Comment: Solved by myself. className={'md:hidden'+ (navbarOpen ? ' flex' : ' hidden')} Thanks a lot!

Comment: nice! you're welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer that I got from Zeke Hernandez in the comment area.

```
className={'md:hidden'+ (navbarOpen ? ' flex' : ' hidden')}
```

This question is now closed. Thanks.